# Hide menu items in small screen AND drop down menu Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Using Bootstrap 3 I'm able to hide two menu items when the screen is resized, as per code example below. Problem is that these items will still show in the drop down menu that appears (on the top left, with three bars), when the screen is resized to a smaller size. Is there a way to keep them hidden there as well ?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li> <a id="mobileTab">Start</a></li>
         <li> <a id="mobilityActivityTab" href="#">Tasks</a></li>
         <li class="hidden-sm"> <a id="activityTab">Activity</a></li>
         <li class="hidden-sm"> <a id="clientAcctTab">Accounts</a></li>
     </ul>
     @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

NOTE: I've removed some code for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

Add the class `hidden-xs` (e.g. hidden on extra small) if you want to hide items when collapsed on mobiles

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li> <a id="mobileTab">Start</a></li>
         <li> <a id="mobilityActivityTab" href="#">Tasks</a></li>
         <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> <a id="activityTab">Activity</a></li>
         <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> <a id="clientAcctTab">Accounts</a></li>
     </ul>
     @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

FYI, there are some handy examples of what classes you can use to show/hide different content for different devices on the Bootstrap website @ http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 0):

add `hidden-xs` before all `hidden-sm`